# NetBeansIDE 7.4 - Can't edit project design in GUIBuilder

Tags: java, netbeans-7, gui-builder

I post this same question in NetBeans Forum, but seems i'm the only one that have this issue.
i try to search for this but i didn't find anything related to.

I'm doing some editing on a project called WebcamStudio:

http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/source/checkout

The project is Written in Java7. I use Java Oracle 1.7 u45 JDK

I run NetBeansIDE 7.4 on Ubuntu 13.10 x64 OS.

I have a problem opening WebcamStudio.java form in the 7.4 GUIBuilder.
When i try to hit the "Design" button, IDE seems to open it, but nothing happens.
The IDE GuiBuilder can open correctly all other projects class form, but not the WebcamStudio Main One.
This issue did not happen with NetBeansIDE 7.3.1 that works correctly.

Any help is appreciated.
karl.

Comment: I did some tests with NetBeansIDE 7.4 and Oracle Java JDK 7u45 under Windows 7 64bit same machine, and the GuiBuilder works well even with WebcamStudio.java form.
Then I should think that the WebcamStudio.java form doesn't have any issue.
I really don't know if it is Ubuntu/Debian based distro related problem.
I will try some other linux/distro configurations.
Hope someone have ideas about this.
Thanks.
karl.

Comment: Seems no one have this issue.
I post a Bug:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238981

I will report here all useful things.
Thanks.
karl.

Comment: Hi,
I decide to give Eclipse a try, and after installing Eclipse Kepler and Subclipse plugin I did a checkout of WebcamStudio source.
I successfully open WebcamStudio main class form in the Design editor without any issue.
At this point i'm quite stuck.
I will study better Eclipse functions because I will continue my work on Eclipse editor.
Thanks.
karl.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, thanks to the NetBeansIDE support, i can switch back editing with NetBeansIDE.

From https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238981 :

Tomas Pavek:
" ... This bug is already fixed in dev builds (8.0) and a fix for 7.4 will be available with patch 2 update next week. ... "

karl